# getting underlying OLE object identity for win32com automation objects

Tags: python-2.x, win32com, sas-jmp

Most built-in Python data types and libraries make a point of returning the *same object* (`a is b`, not just `a==b`) even if you ask for it in different ways. A very simple example:

```
list = [ "foo", "bar", {"name": [1,2,3]} ]
a = list[-1]["name"]
b = list[2].values()[0]
print (a is b) # True!
```

However, this doesn't seem to be the case for many kinds of non-scalar objects returned by `win32com` automation. The following code connects to [sas-jmp](/questions/tagged/sas-jmp) automation and then gets two handles to the same data table object. At the Python level, these two automation objects don't share an identity:

```
from win32com.client import gencache
mod = gencache.GetModuleForProgID("JMP.Application")
app = mod.Application()
table = app.GetTableHandleFromName("Table1")
same_table = app.GetTableHandleFromName("Table1")
print table
print same_table
print table is same_table
# <win32com.gen_py.DCD36DE0-78F8-11CF-9E68-0020AF24E9FEx0x1x0.IAutoDataTable instance at 0x54418504>
# <win32com.gen_py.DCD36DE0-78F8-11CF-9E68-0020AF24E9FEx0x1x0.IAutoDataTable instance at 0x54432456>
# False
```

It appears that all `win32com` OLE automation objects also have an `_oleobj_` property. `_oleobj_` is a [PyIDispatch object](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.1/pywin32/PyIDispatch.html), which only has a few methods, none of which seem pertinent to the question of object identity. However, the `repr()` of `_oleobj_` seems to point to the underlying OLE automation object:

```
print table._oleobj_
print same_table._oleobj_
# <PyIDispatch at 0x0000000003459530 with obj at 0x00000000003E2928>
# <PyIDispatch at 0x0000000003459620 with obj at 0x00000000003E2928>
```

In order to confirm that two objects refer to the same underlying OLE object, I've resorted to parsing the `repr()` strings and comparing the hexadecimal addresses ("`obj at 0x...`").

**Is there a better, cleaner way to compare OLE object identity using `win32com`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Smacks self in face***

It turns out there's quite an easy way to do this: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2014-October/013288.html

Although the `is` operator does not work since the *Python* objects are distinct, the `==` object accomplishes this purpose with `win32com`-wrapped objects:

```
from win32com.client import gencache
mod = gencache.GetModuleForProgID("JMP.Application")
app = mod.Application()
table = app.GetTableHandleFromName("Table1")
same_table = app.GetTableHandleFromName("Table1")
print table is same_table, table._oleobj_ is same_table._oleobj_
print table==same_table, table._oleobj_==same_table._oleobj_
# False, False
# True, True
```